# Bayesian Modeling of Pre-Post Study with Counts Including Zeros in Baseline

Tags: regression, bayesian, poisson-regression, pre-post-comparison

I'm working with data from a pre-post study examining colony-forming unit (CFU) counts before and after the application of a disinfectant. My primary goal is to model whether there's a negative trend in the CFU count from the pre-treatment phase (denoted $t_0$) to the post-treatment phase (denoted $t_1$).

I'm trying to evaluate the ratio:

$\frac{t_1}{t_0} = k$

with the hypothesis that
$k$ is less than 1. To adopt a regression approach, I've transformed the model to:

$$\log(t_1) - \log(t_0) = k \implies \log(t_1) = k + \log(t_0)$$

Which then becomes:

$$t_1 \sim Poisson(\exp(\lambda))$$
$$\lambda = k \times I(t_0 > 0) + \log(t_0)$$

That is, I assumed that if the baseline is zero, also the post-treatment count would be zero plus Poisson noise.

However, I run into an issue when $t0$ is zero, as the logarithm becomes $-\infty$. I solved switching the zeroes to 1 in both $t0$ and $t1$ (LaPlace smoothing?), but I'm not sure is the best approach.

So:
How should I handle situations where the baseline is zero in Poisson models?
Are there alternative models or strategies that might be more appropriate for this kind of data?
Are there example papers or resources that have dealt with similar modeling issues?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!